# Force HTTPS in Nginx for Django

Tags: django, nginx, django-admin

I have tried to do this:

1. Create a file named middleware.py (chmod 775, chown www-data) in the same directory as my settings.py
2. Paste this in middleware.py: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/880/
3. Paste this in my settings.py:

   ```
   MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = ( #...
       'djo.middleware.SSLRedirect',
   )

   SSL_ENABLED = True
   SSL_URLS = (
       r'/admin/',
   )
   ```

I get: **Internal Server Error**

No errors in the development server shown.

Suggestions?

Comment: did you check error log ?

Comment: Nginx is not throwing any errors, and the django server shows only a get request. The browser only displays "A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator." Can you think of somewhere else to try looking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. I had an infinite loop happening and followed this site to fix it:

http://yuji.wordpress.com/2008/08/15/django-nginx-making-ssl-work-on-django-behind-a-reverse-proxy/#comment-1941

Basically, add this to the nginx server conf setting under the proxy location part of the file:

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = (‘HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTOCOL’, $scheme)
```

Then add to your django settings file:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (...
'djo.middleware.SecureRequiredMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'djo.urls'

HTTPS_SUPPORT = True
SECURE_REQUIRED_PATHS = (
    r'/admin/',
```

Then create a file in the same django directory called "middleware.py" with the following contents:

```
from django.http import HttpResponsePermanentRedirect
from django.conf import settings
class SecureRequiredMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.paths = getattr(settings, 'SECURE_REQUIRED_PATHS')
        self.enabled = self.paths and getattr(settings, 'HTTPS_SUPPORT')

    def process_request(self, request):
        if self.enabled and not request.is_secure():
            for path in self.paths:
                if request.get_full_path().startswith(path):
                    request_url = request.build_absolute_uri(request.get_full_path())
                    secure_url = request_url.replace('http://', 'https://')
                    print self.paths, request_url, secure_url
                    return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(secure_url)
        return None
```

Voilá! Redirects for any base url desired.